# What is a good reference to explain the different protestant sects and denominations?

Tags: protestantism, resource-request

I would like to gain clarity on the definitions of evangelical, Presbyterian,  Baptist, Methodist, Pentecostal, Calvinist, Jesuit, Lutheran, Quaker, puritan, and others.  It should explain the main differences and how they evolved.  Free but accurate online resources only please.

Comment: Most of those are Protestant, except Jesuit, which is an order of the Catholic Church...

Comment: This particular book how almost all Christian denominations differ from the perspective of Eastern Orthodoxy:  [*Orthodoxy and Heterodoxy: Finding the Way to Christ in a Complicated Religious Landscape*](http://amzn.to/2qipQVz).  It is based on the [podcast](https://www.ancientfaith.com/podcasts/orthodoxyheterodoxy) of the same name by the same author.

Answer (score 2):

For **ease of access** and **breadth of scope**, it would be hard to go past Wikipedia. Perhaps you should start with either their article on [Protestantism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestantism) or the one on [Christian denominations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_denomination) and then start chasing links from there.

Answer (score 0):

I saw [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1426700482) at a used book store ans almost bought it once purely out of curiosity.  If you're American it probably will give you a pretty good understanding of the multitudinous denominations.  It's fairly amazing that such a thing can even exist.

> A helpful resource for clergy, laity, journalists, and researchers, this authoritative guidebook to U.S. religions is grouped in family categories of Abrahamic religions, arranged chronologically: Judaism, Christianity, and Islam. The information for each group within these families has been provided by the religious organizations themselves and focuses on the denominations' doctrines, statistics, and histories.
>
> Handbook of Denominations - Amazon Blurb

I think the older editions didnt have Islam and Judaism in there, but I could be mistaken (my last recollection of the book was spending half an hour reading it in a bookstore 15 years ago)

Comment: Aww crud, I missed tge "free online" part. Well, you can look up libraries where this book is available online!